# Question about the degree of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose that $\phi$ is a morphism between compleax algebraic varieties named $X$ and $Y$. I know that the degree of the morphism $\phi= [Rat(X):Rat(Y)]$. Suppose that $\phi$ is a one degree morphism.
With this assumptions is it true that $\phi$ is a 1 to 1 morphism?

Answer (score 3):

$\phi$ is degree one if and only if it is an isomorphism from an open subset of $X$ to an open subset of $Y$ (i.e. it is birational). So it is generically one-to-one. But birational maps can be far from injective.

As counterexamples, consider blowups of varieties along closed subvarieties. These are always birational but never injective.

What you can say is that the map $\phi$ is dominant and hence surjective if $X$ is proper.

Comment: for example if i take $X=S$ with $S$ a surface of general type and $\phi$ is the 1-canonical map and suppose that $\phi$ is a morphism of degree one. is it true that $\phi$ is an embedding from $S$ to a subset of the projective space?

Comment: In your question, you seemed to assume that the morphism from $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension (otherwise, the dimension you used in the definition of the degree is not finite). Is that not the case?

Comment: Let me try to explain. The problem rises from that sistuation. I have a surface that is a complex algenraic surfaces of general type with the assumptions that the 1 canonical map of the canonical divisor $K_S$ is a morphism of degree one. Then i find on my book that that surface is embedded in the projective space of dimension $p_g=h^0(K_S)-1$. I wolud like to prove this assertion. I'm not sure that is true. Is this explanation  usefull?

Comment: I see the context now. I'm not sure if I can help you unfortunately.

Comment: do you have some references about degree of morphism?

Comment: @dario: The degree of a morphism is discussed in Hartshorne (probably even in Chapter I), but this is not going to help you.   You need to learn something about canonical embeddings, and something about surfaces. You might want to first think about the case of canonically embedded curves, discussed in Hartshorne Ch. IV.    I don't remember that Hartshorne discusses the canonical map for surfaces in Ch. V, but you could look there to check.  You might also want to learn about *minimal models* of surfaces.  (If a surface is not minimal, then its canonical divisor restricts to a divisor of ...

Comment: ... negative degree along some curve, and so the canonical map will contain that curve in its base-locus.  So in your set-up, it is quite possibly assumed that the surface is minimal.)  I also just googled "canonically embedded surfaces" and found various interesting hits; you could try doing the same.

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh i've found a theorem that is usefull in this case but i need that the image under the 1 canonical map must be a surface. Can i ensure that using the assumptions in my question?

Comment: I believe a degree one map should be birational onto its image (though I can't find a reference for this or think of a direct proof at the moment). In this case, if the domain variety is proper, then the image must be a closed subvariety of the same dimension as the domain and hence a surface.